# How do I generate objects randomly in java?

Tags: java, object, oop, inheritance, random

I have an abstract class called "Student" and 2 subclasses "Graduate" and "Undergraduate", they both have the same parameters.

I want to create 10 Student objects randomly, some from the "Graduate" and some from the "Undergraduate" classes.

I want to print the displayStudent() method for all objects created, I got stuck on how to randomly generate the 10 students so they are all random of type graduates and undergraduates.

```
public abstract class Student {
    private int ID;
    private double GPA;
    
    public Student(int ID, double GPA) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.GPA = GPA;
    }
    
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return GPA;
    }
    
    public abstract String getLevel();

    
    public abstract String getStatus();
    
    public final String displayStudent() {
        return getLevel() + " ID>> " + getID() + ", GPA>> " + getGPA() + ", Status>> " + getStatus();
    }

} 


    public class Graduate extends Student{
    
    public Graduate(int ID, double GPA) {
        super(ID, GPA);
    }
    @Override
    public String getLevel() {
        return "graduate";
    }

    @Override
    public String getStatus() {
        if( getGPA() >= 3) {
            return "honor";
        } else if (getGPA() >= 2 && getGPA() <= 3) {
            return "good";
        } else {
            return "probation";
        }
    }
}
 

public class Undergraduate extends Student {
    public Undergraduate(int ID, double GPA) {
        super(ID, GPA);
    }

    @Override
    public String getLevel() {
        return "undergraduate";
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getStatus() {
        if( getGPA() >= 3) {
            return "honor";
        } else if (getGPA() >= 2 && getGPA() <= 3) {
            return "good";
        } else if( getGPA() > 0 && getGPA() < 2) {
            return "probation";
        } else {
            //for any number that is not in the range of the GPA
            return "invalid GPA!";
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use `java.util.Random` to get random numbers and fill out fields like ID/GPA, build your logic based on the returned values (I leave this to you) ...

Comment: I know how to generate the random numbers, but I couldn't figure out how to make it randomly choose between graduate and undergraduate. Appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: I will give you a hint ... how would you use java.util.Random to represent head and tail?? Now, how would you use java.util.Random to represent Graduate and Undergraduate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

- using the ternary operator `?:` is key.

  - `exp ? a : b` says if `exp` is true, do `a`, else do `b`
- I used the loop index+1 as the id.
- If the boolean is true, graduate, otherwise undergrad.
- The double is multiplied by `4` to get the GPA.

```
Random r = new Random();

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    students.add(r.nextBoolean() ?
            new Graduate(i+1, r.nextDouble() * 4) :
            new Undergraduate(i+1, r.nextDouble() * 4));
}
```

Note, If you change the `displayStudent()` method to `toString()` like so

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getLevel() + " ID>> " + getID() + ", GPA>> "
            + getGPA() + ", Status>> " + getStatus();
}
```

You can just print the object directly without having to call any method.

You will probably need to format the GPA to eliminate unnecessary precision.  Check out [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: It's obvious that this is being asked by a Student ... Give him the final solution is a bad approach (from a learning perspective, of course) ...

Comment: Normally I would agree.  But in this case, the OP already had given significant code and admitted they couldn't figure this part out.